# Give the CFG for $L= \{a^i b^j c^m d^n | i+j= m+n\}$

Tags: computational-mathematics, context-free-grammar

I am not able to come up with the solution.

EDIT :
I was trying something like this :

S $\to$ AB

A $\to$ abB | ^

B $\to$ Acd

But clearly it does not makes any sense. For every call to `A` there must be a call to `B`.
I am not just able to express it.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: You must have tried something. Please share your thoughts on the problem. We encourage learning here.

Comment: what is CFG....

Comment: Context Free Grammar

Comment: @Shaun Sure sir
let me edit the description

Answer (score 1):

If this solution seems strange, it may seem less so if you tackle [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548882/cfg-for-this-language) first. We introduce two non-terminals, $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$  - the first will produce all legal strings with more $a$s than $d$s, and the second will produce more $d$s than $a$s. For the first we give the production rules
\begin{align}
&L_{1} \to aL_{1}d\\
&L_{1} \to M_{1} \\
&M_{1} \to aM_{1}c \\
&M_{1} \to N_{1} \\
&N_{1} \to bN_{1}c
\end{align}
Similarly,
\begin{align}
&L_{2} \to aL_{2}d\\
&L_{2} \to M_{2} \\
&M_{2} \to bM_{2}d \\
&M_{2} \to N_{2} \\
&N_{2} \to bN_{2}c
\end{align}
Clearly distinguishing between $N_{1}$ and $N_{2}$ is unnecessary, but I think it makes the presentation more readable. 
Finally, to formally put this into a proper CFG we add in
\begin{align}
S \to L_{1}\\
S \to L_{2}\\
N_{1} \to \varepsilon\\
N_{2} \to \varepsilon
\end{align}
where $S$ is the start symbol, and $\varepsilon$ is the empty string.